# How to access the Idle Air Control Valve, Renault Clio mk2

Tags: renault, air-intake, stall

I have an idling issue with my Renault Clio mk2 1.2L 2002 - the engine stalls as I slow down at lights and roundabouts etc...

I have been searching the web for solutions to this problem, Most answers point towards the Idle Air Control valve needing cleaning/replacing - I am now trying to locate it in the engine I did find a diagram, however I am not sure if it is accurate.

[image]

How do I get to the IACV, or even better do you have a few pictures/video demonstrating how to access it?

Thanks.

Comment: A bad IACV is one of many potential causes for your symptoms. In my experience it is not guaranteed that the common problems faced by folks online is representative of what your car is experiencing. How sure are you that the IACV is bad?

Comment: Love your car!  Wish they were in the states.  Can I borrow it for a track day.  I promise, it won't be idling very much at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idle air control valve is integrated into the throttle body unit as shown here:

[image]

It may not look *exactly* like that, there was an update some time around then but the parts are very similar and the principles are the same.

There is a forum thread with a few more pictures of the cleaning process here:
http://www.renaultforums.co.uk/showthread.php?t=65279

[image]

[image]

*Please note:* Moving the throttle butterfly manually may mean you need to undertake a 'throttle body reset' as the throttle is computer controlled and has no physical link to the pedal. The process is discussed and explained here in post 14.
http://www.cliosport.net/threads/dont-touch-throttle-body.321352/

*This is the process described:*

> **Minimum throttle stop must be reprogrammed as follows:**
>   a) switch the ignition on for approx. 3 secs
>   b)switch off he ignition and wait aprox, 5 secs
>   c) restart the engine and allow the coolant temperature to reach 60°C (approx. 3 mins from ambient temp of 20°C
>   d) road test the car and allow the ECU to learn the throttle valve adaptives

Comment: It's better for you to capture the main highlights on how to clean the IAC here rather than just provide an external link. This way, if the external link becomes inaccessible for whatever reason the how-to is still present over here. The answer looks great otherwise :)

Answer (score 1):

By the way, this:

> the throttle is computer controlled and has no physical link to the pedal

is incorrect. This is me pushing the lever on my Clio 2 1.2 8V 2007 throttle that the wire that the pedal pulls actuates:

[image: Clio 2 throttle body with open throttle]

As you can clearly see, the throttle butterfly valve is open because I push the lever. This means that the throttle pedal actually **does have a physical link to the throttle valve**! The only thing that is computer controlled is the idler valve, but I don't know how you would move that, since it is pretty hard to get to and spring-loaded, so if you move it, it will go back to the original (closed) position anyway. Anyway, even those computer-actuated throttle valves actually are spring-loaded too. And if your throttle is computer-actuated, you probably do not have any idler valve, because the computer does the same with the throttle valve.